# rejected by Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, ads

I am trying to test calls to Facebook's ads api using a whitelisted app that my company has registered. I've been added to our app as a developer, and also have the login for a marketing account. So using the graph api explorer tool, I select the whitelisted app, generate an access token, and make a simple POST request to /act_MYID/adcampaigns, which gives me this error:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) User MYID does not have access to account MYID", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 10
  }
}
umm... excuse me?? my account doesn't have access to my own account? sorry but wtf does that mean...

I've also tried replacing MYID with the marketing account id, same error but the 2nd MYID is replaced with marketing account id.

Could anyone please shed some light on this? Facebook's error documentation is shoddy and no luck searching for the error.

Answer (score 1):

that error occurs usually when you're generating an access token while logged in with one account, and then trying to use the same access token with another account, so make sure you're using the same account (trivial, but sometimes these mistakes can happen).

if that checks out, verify that you're checking the ads_management checkbox in the extended permissions tab while generating the access token in the graph api.

Comment: I am generating the access token while logged in on my dev account, and making the post request on the url with my dev account id, I also checked the ads_management in extended permissions.

Comment: Are you doing this with the gray account? Also called a corporate account. It could be that Facebook hasn't whitelisted your app (even though they claim to have). Might want to check with them first.

Another way to get the access token is through code. Take a look at the documentation here -
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/)

Look at the Provide Authentication section. Basically, you can create a redirect uri at your end and call Facebook with these same parameters and get an access token back.